# Obter valor de DropDown quando Textbox receber foco

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

O que posso fazer para conseguir o valor que está selecionado em um `DropDownList` e passar para um `TextBox` somente quando o `Textbox` receber o foco (quando o usuário clicar no campo)?

Eu já havia colocado um `Autopostaback` no `DropDownList` pra envia-o valor pro `TextBox` mais não gostei do desempenho.

*Alguma sugestão?*

Comment: Olá, Para ser em C# tem que fazer a chamada ao servidor por isso tem que utilizar o PostBack. Poderá ser em javascript ou jquery?

Comment: Olá, pode ser sim, javascript ou jquery, como ficaria? como posso pegar o evento de "focus" no javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Exemplo minimo***

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#txt1').on('focus', function() {
    var element = $("#select1 option:selected");
    var text = $(element).text();    
    var value = $(element).val();
    if (text === '-Selecione-')
    {
      text = "";
      value = "";
    }
    $(this).val(value + ' ' + text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="select1" name="select1">
    <option value="">-Selecione-</option>
    <option value="1">Stackoverflow</option>
    <option value="2">Meta</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" />
</div>
```

No exemplo é mostrado na caixa de texto o valor selecionado e o texto do `select` como está no exemplo, pode ser utilizado qualquer um ou os dois.

***Exemplo em ASP.Net WebForms***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListItens" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="-Selecione-" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Stackoverflow" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Meta" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxItens" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#<%=TextBoxItens.ClientID%>').on('focus', function () {
                var element = $("#<%=DropDownListItens.ClientID%> option:selected");
                var text = $(element).text();
                var value = $(element).val();
                if (text === '-Selecione-') {
                    text = "";
                    value = "";
                }
                $(this).val(value + ' ' + text);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito bom! era exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado!